# How to statically include unmanaged C++ in a managed C# wrapper dll?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, dll

In Visual Studio, I have a project (lets call it Project A) which is an unmanaged C++ function library. I have a second project (B) which is a managed C# class library. Finally, I have a third project (C), which is a C# application.

Project C needs to create instances of classes in Project B, and at least one class in Project B needs to call one or more of the functions in Project A, so it goes C -> B -> A.

After searching around a bit I think I have found at least half of a method to do this:

1. Build Project A into an unmanaged C-style DLL, call it `A.dll`
2. For each class in B that needs functions in A, import them as static methods via `ImportDll`
3. Build Project B as a managed C# DLL, call it `B.dll`
4. ...

Here's where things get a little hazy for me. As far as I can tell, if I want to use classes and methods from `B.dll` in Project C, then I must have both A and B `.dlls` 'imported' somehow into Project C. In other words, I don't think that I can just add `B.dll` as a referenced assembly and have `C.exe` run successfully; `A.dll` must somehow also make its way to the output folder of Project C.

Assuming that is the case, I would have to add `B.dll` to Project C as a referenced assembly, but add `A.dll` as an "Existing Item," since you cannot add C-style unmanaged DLLs as referenced assemblies. I would also then have to select "Copy if newer" in the properties for the new `A.dll` item

I think this would work, but my question is: is there a better way? Is there a way to somehow statically embed the unmanaged functions of Project A inside the managed dll of Project B, so that I only need to reference the `B.dll` from Project C? i.e. I don't want to have to import both A.dll and B.dll into Project C.

Comment: You could combine the libraries into a [mixed-mode assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/mixed-native-and-managed-assemblies?view=msvc-170), but that seems like an unnecessary complication. Most non-trivial applications very often require several libraries in the final distribution, so I'm not really seeing what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried building a C++/cli dll?  You can then also use C++/cli to write a nice managed/unmanaged wrapper that manages the interop

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have not, but does that solve the issue of having to import `A.dll` into Project C? i.e. will I be able to reference only the C++/CLI DLL from Project C?

Comment: Yes it should be possible, I think you can try it quickly (sorry I don't have time today to setup a demo project).  [quick introduction  to c++/cli](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes).  In general I think this is the best way to glue C++/C# together anyway (lots of control over managed/unmanaged and when to pin/unpin managed memory)

Comment: So what you do is, with C++/cli you can build a .Net dll (.Net doesn't have static libararies at all). But with C++/cli you can link that .dll statically with C++ libraries.

Comment: What's wrong with your existing design? That is exactly how you are supposed to do it: add the DLL as an uncompiled item.

Comment: Do you have static version library A?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Not yet- and I have the source for A, so I can compile to a static library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# itself does not use static libraries. You need to create B as  C++/CLR Class Library. Download  C++CLI  build tools  in   Visual Studio Installer.

Sample:
Static Library A:

Header.h

```
void fnCLib();
```

Cpp

```
#include "framework.h"
#include"Header.h"
#include<iostream>
// TODO: This is an example of a library function
void fnCLib()
{
    std::cout << "Cpp Lib";
}
```

C++ CLR   library   B (Such as .NetFramework)

Add Static Lib A as dependency in project's properties:
Right Click project -> properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories: Add the folder path of `A.lib`.
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependency -> Type A.lib.

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
#include"... /PATH/ Header.h"
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public :
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
        void test()
        {
            fnCLib();
        }
    };
}
```

C# (.NetFramework) project C:
Add B project reference: Right Click  C  project-> Add -> Reference -> B project or Browser -> search the B.dll

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Class1 temp = new Class1();
     temp.test();
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

You need to specify that the C# project's platform is consistent with the C++ lib.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't though of making B a C++ CLR project instead of a C# one.